# Where to find MIBS for HP Series Router A-MSR20-20

Tags: router, snmp, hp

I currently have an HP MSR20-20 router and am trying to make heads and tails of the snmpbulkwalk output.  The majority of it is what i'd expect such as

```
ifIndex.1 = INTEGER:1
ifDescr.1 = STRING: Ethernet0/0
ifType.1 = INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)
```

However, I get to a later point in the output where I see the following

```
mib-2.3.1.1.1.1.1.196.168.1.100 = INTEGER:1
mib-2.3.1.1.1.1.1.196.168.1.103 = INTEGER:1
mib-2.3.1.1.1.1.1.196.168.1.104 = INTEGER:1
```

Is there a MIB database I can reference to understand the mib-2.3.1.1.1.1.1 and other MIBS that aren't described in a readable manner?  I'm assuming this means that the switch, which is off of ETH/0 can route to 192.168.1.100

However, some other documentation would be really helpful.  I'll assume my google-fu is a bit off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since the OID starts with MIB-2, you need the MIB-II mib described in RFC 1213 here : https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1213.txt

In this case, mib-2.3.1.1.1.1.1.196.168.1.100 refers to an entry in the Address Table group (mib-2.3), which is deprecated but still available on many devices for backwards compatibility, and basically gives you access to the device's ARP table. The table is indexed by interface index and ip address.

You can usually find MIBs by just googling an OID that you have (or at least the beginning of the OID). Cisco also has a good OID lookup tool on its site at http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en

Comment: Great!  One slightly on/off topic question.  Any idea why a router when running snmpwalk on it would return the MIB instead of a description?  For example return atTable instead of the long mib

Comment: It's actually probably your tool which is doing that, presenting a user friendly abbreviation rather than a raw OID. This is often the case for the most common standard MIBs, which are baked into the SNMP tools themselves.

Comment: And actually, it you are using snmpwalk, you can specify the -On option to display the "raw" OIDs rather than the MIB abbreviations. See here for details: http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpcmd.html